# Anaconda3 install hanging on install.py

Tags: python, anaconda

I've tried everything I know to install Anaconda3 64 bit on a Windows 10 system that takes automatic updates. It is hanging at this line:

"Execute: "d:\Anaconda3\tFF16.tmp.dir\pythonw.exe" -E -s "d:\Anaconda3\pkgs.install.py""

I've removed all path entries for python. Disabled my anti-virus (ESET). Tried the 32 bit version.

As part of my own attempt to find the problem, I deleted the directory without ending the install program and the following file was locked:

conda-build-3.17.6.py37_0

When I looked with the task manager, it said Python.exe was in a suspended state.

Any advice at all? I've been at this for two days, off and on.